# How could I solve this onclick-onblur problem?

Tags: javascript, click, onclick, textarea, onblur

I have a form. In it I have a textarea which expands when onclick.
But there is a little problem:
When the user tries to submit the form (click the submit button), the textarea jumps back to its normal size. This is because it uses the onblur function. I want to eliminate this awkwardness, because the user has to click the submit button twice to submit the form.

What should I do to make it work with one click?

Comment: Do you have any code to post?

Comment: Well, I thought that this problem can be solved without posting the code, but if you need the piece of code just notify me.

Comment: It would certainly be helpful if you could post a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.com/ because an example usually says more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a short timeout in the onblur handler that shrinks the text area:

```
document.getElementById("textareaID").onblur = function () {
    var target = this;
    setTimeout( function () {
        //Code to shrink the textarea, use "target" instead of "this" for scoping reasons.
    }, 250);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
textArea.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, true);
```

This will add a listener to the `blur` event which will prevent anything else from firing, including whatever it is that's causing the `textarea` to re-resize.  It'd be easier for you to *not* add the `blur` hook in the first place, rather than catching it this way, though.